# How to Sort by Long field in Lucene

Tags: java, sorting, lucene

```
//create
Document doc = new Document();
//get value from JDBC ResultSet
doc.add(new LongDocValuesField("LastContactTime", rs.getLong("LastContactTime")));
//....
//Search
Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField("LastContactTime",
                    SortField.Type.LONG, false));
TopDocs rs = scher.search(query, total, sort);
```

The results are not sorted correctly,Why?
I'm using Lucene4.0

Comment: What is the output? What is the expected output? Error messages? Are you using the correct type for the field?

Comment: no Exception occured,but order is not correct

Answer (score 1):

[LongDocValuesField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-ALPHA/core/org/apache/lucene/document/LongDocValuesField.html) is somewhat different in nature from a [LongField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/document/LongField.html).

It looks like (according to: http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/377217) you may be able to sort on them simply by calling setUseIndexValues, like:

```
SortField field = new SortField("LastContactTime",
                SortField.Type.LONG, false);
field.setUseIndexValues(true);
Sort sort = new Sort(sort);
```